# open auth introspection with okta authentication

Tags: .net, vue.js, oauth, introspection

I am trying to introspect token recieved from okta inside .net core api, but keep getting "token is not active".
With the setup you see bellow I am able to retrieve identity from token.(basic okta auth schema)

```
service.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;         
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultSignInScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
   })
   .AddOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
   {
   OktaDomain = configuration["Authentication:Okta:OktaDomain"],
   AuthorizationServerId = configuration["Authentication:Okta:AuthorizationServerId"],
   Audience = configuration["Authentication:Okta:Audience"]});
```

But I need to set up authentication with "Introspection" schema here is my configuration:

```
service.AddAuthentication(auth =>     
    {
     auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Introspection";
       auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Introspection";
       auth.DefaultSignInScheme = "Introspection";
       })
       .AddOAuth2Introspection("Introspection", options =>
       {
       options.Authority = configuration["Authentication:Okta:Authority"];
       options.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Okta:ClientId"];     
       options.TokenRetriever = request =>
    
       {
       string token = "";                
       if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
       {                
        var parts = request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Split(" ");
        token = parts[1];
        return token;
       }
            if (request.Query.ContainsKey("access_token"))
            {
                token = request.Query["access_token"];
            }
            if (request.Cookies.ContainsKey("access_token"))
            {
                token = request.Cookies["access_token"];
            }
            return token;
        };
    });
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
There is a **IntrospectionEndpoint** property on IntrospectionOptions where you can specify full path including the authenticationServerID.
Also need to add that for some authServer there no authServID at all and you can use authority where you just specifying domain( https://domain) and all the rest is done by introspectionHandler

Comment: Would you recommend introspect over local token validation after using it for some time? Do you notice network latency due to sending the request? Also do you do validate the token every request when someone makes a api call to your controllers?

Comment: @IrishRedneck Yes, I do the validation for each request. You can set refresh token option in your okta app which will cause revalidation if you want it to be temporary.
And no, no latency issue were ever noticed